# join update of multiple rows on child table

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

```
parent_table:
ID  | FIELD1 | FIELD2
____|________|________
1   |........|......
2   |........|.....
3   |.............. 

child_table:
ID | FIELD3
___|________
1  |   18
1  |   7
2  |   ..
1  |   ..
3  |   ..
2  |   ..
```

Let's say I want to update these tables.
This is what I need to achieve:

```
 UPDATE parent_table SET 
   FIELD1 = 'XXX', 
   FIELD2 = 'YYY' 
 WHERE ID = 2;

 DELETE FROM child_table 
 WHERE ID = 2;

 INSERT INTO child_table (ID, FIELD3)
   VALUES (2, 50),
   VALUES (2, 17),
   VALUES (2, 9);
```

note that the number of entries in the child table for each ID may vary during the update.

Is it possible to get the same result in just one query?
I can't use a transaction.

maybe the first two queries are easier to merge.
I tried to join the child table and set null values during the UPDATE, but I don't know how to handle the multiple rows.. 
Is it possible to have nested UPDATE like you have nested SELECT?

Answer (score 1):

You can update multiple tables in one command:

```
UPDATE parent_table p LEFT JOIN child_table c On p.id = c.id
 SET 
   p.FIELD1 = 'XXX', 
   p.FIELD2 = 'YYY',
   c.FIELD3 = ''
 WHERE p.ID = 2;
```

However, I don't think that you can preform update and delete in the same command - but I must admit I'm not sure about it.

You can read more about multiple tables update [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

A different (and preferred) approach will be to create a trigger on parent_table that will delete the relevant records from child_table upon update.

Comment: of course, the problem is: how do I update multiple rows in the joined table? even if putting a CASE sentence in there were allowed (idk), how does that account for a mismatch between the number of entries in the table, and the number I want to update? For example.. here there are two entries for ID=2, but what if I wanted to put another? .. maybe UPDATE just can't do it.

Comment: by putting "another" you mean: changing both ID 2 and ID3 for example ?

Comment: no, i mean that if `FIELD3` were a string set to `"5,40,15"` I may need to update it to `"3,5,7,8,15,7"`, ie  I mean that the number of rows in `child_table` may vary.

Comment: i could do an  `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..  ` but there's no `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key in my table, and there can't be

Comment: In that case I think that I would create a DB procedure that receives all the parameters and runs the updates and inserts serially.

Comment: is it possible with myIsam engine?

Comment: yes, but transactions are not supported: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0596100892/mysqlspp-CHP-8-SECT-1?portal=oreilly#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTA1OTYxMDA4OTIvbXlzcWxzcHAtQ0hQLTgtU0VDVC0x